# ib/src/screens//log_screens.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/src/screens/mixins/validation_mixin.dart': The system cannot find

Tags: flutter, dart

lib/src/screens//log_screens.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading
'lib/src/screens/mixins/validation_mixin.dart': The system cannot find
the path specified.
Performing hot restart...

Performing hot restart...
import '../mixins/validation_mixin.dart';
Performing hot restart...
^
Performing hot restart...
lib/src/screens//log_screens.dart:10:56: Error: Type 'ValidationMixin'
not found.
Performing hot restart...
class LoginScreenState extends State with ValidationMixin
{
Performing hot restart...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Performing hot restart...
lib/src/screens//log_screens.dart:10:7: Error: The type
'ValidationMixin' can't be mixed in.

I wanted to use mixins class always I am getting path not found .